# UTC date to CST date

Tags: t-sql

I need help converting UTC date that is saved as the bigint number 1538397000000  to a CST datetime.
I have tried

```
       select 
        Dateadd(s,convert(Bigint,1538397000000/1000,convert(datetime,'1-1-1970'))
```

Comment: Why are you storing dates as big int to begin with? Why not store them properly, as `Date` or `DateTime2`?

Comment: This is data from a vendor and that is how they store the data.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function that converts UTC to local time.  Assuming your above code correctly converts the `bigint` to a proper UTC date/time value, then the following will convert that value to CST.

```
create function UTCDateTimeToLocal(@value datetime) returns datetime as
begin
  declare @utc datetime = getutcdate()
         ,@local datetime = getdate()
         ,@diff int
         ,@rtn datetime

  set @diff = datediff(millisecond, @utc, @local)
  set @rtn = dateadd(millisecond, @diff, @value)

  return @rtn
end
go

select dbo.UTCDateTimeToLocal(dateadd(s,cast(1538397000000/1000 as bigint),convert(datetime,'1-1-1970')))

--drop function UTCDateTimeToLocal
```

Comment: UTCDateTimeLocal is not being recognized in SQl Server 2016

Comment: I forgot that `UTCDateTimeToLocal()` is a function I wrote.  I updated the answer to include the SQL for the function.  I've just used it for so long that I thought it was part of SQL Server...  Sorry about that!